# ¿Cómo hacer para que el usuario pueda escoger el nombre del archivo al guardar en Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación (utilizando tkinter) en el cual se ingresan ciertos parámetros en diferentes Entry como se aprecia en la imagen. La idea es que lo escrito en las Entry sea capaz de guardarse en un archivo Excel, para ello utilicé `filedialog.asksavesfile` (es un *guardar como* utilizado en barraMenu), lo cual me funciona sin problemas pero como se aprecia en el código solo se guarda con el nombre RMR.

Quiero que el usuario sea capaz de guardar el archivo en Excel utilizando el nombre que él desee (con la intención de que sea capaz de crear más de un archivo Excel); el problema es que al intentar guardar el archivo con un nombre diferente solo me sobreescribe el Excel creado con el nombre RMR y no me crea uno nuevo, sé que es por utilizar `[df.to_excel("RMR.xlsx")]`, pero no sé cómo hacer para que se guarde con el nombre escogido por el usuario (la idea es que el programa sea utilizable en cualquier PC).

[image: Imagen de las Entry]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
     def AgrDatos():
        global Res1,RQD1,EspD1,LongD1,Abrt1,Rug1
    
        Res1.append(textoResCp.get())
        Res2.append(textoResCu.get())
        RQD1.append(textoRQD.get())
        EspD1.append(textoEsp.get())
        LongD1.append(textoLong.get())
        Abrt1.append(textoAb.get())


#--------------Menu------------------------

    def infoAd():
        messagebox.showinfo("Acerca de...","Software")
    def avisoLi():
        messagebox.showwarning("Licencia","Producto licencia BrMt")
    def salirApp():
        valSal=messagebox.askquestion("Salir","¿Quieres salir de la aplicación?")
        if valSal=="yes":
            ventana1.destroy()

    def abreFich():
        fich=filedialog.askopenfile(title="Abrir",filetypes=(("Ficheros Excel","*.xlsx"),("Ficheros Texto","*.txt")))
        
    def GuarFich():
        fichg=filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode="w",title="Guardar",filetypes=(("Ficheros Excel","*.xlsx"),("Ficheros Texto","*.txt")))
        global Res1,RQD1,EspD1,LongD1,Abrt1,Rug1
    
        datos={"Carga Puntual (Mpa)":Res1,"RCU (Mpa)":Res2,"RQD":RQD1,"Espaciamiento Discontinuidades (m)":EspD1,"Longitud Discontinuidades (m)":LongD1,
        "Abertura (m)":Abrt1,"Rugosidad":Rug1}
        df=pd.DataFrame(datos,columns=["Carga Puntual (Mpa)","RCU (Mpa)","RQD","Espaciamiento Discontinuidades (m)","Longitud Discontinuidades (m)",
        "Abertura (m)","Rugosidad"])
        df.to_excel("RMR.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes implementar el siguiente código que aprovecha las funcionalidades de "filedialog" en tkinter:

```
from tkinter import filedialog

string = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Guardar como",filetypes = (("Python","*.py"),("todos los archivos","*.*")))
        if string != '':
            # código
```

El condicional ayuda a controlar el caso en el que el usuario presione el botón cancelar en la ventana, en el cual la función asksaveasfilename retorna el valor ''. Si el usuario guarda el archivo, dicha función retornará la dirección que se escogió para la acción, incluyendo el nombre del archivo al final. (por ejemplo: "C:/Program Files/Python/test.py").